# Remove current fragment in onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity Aa with Fragment Fa . Using childfragmentmanager in Fa I open another Fragment Frag. Using Fragment Frag I am starting another activity Ba using startActivityforresult. My usecase is to not to go back to Fragment frag if I successfully start activity Ba. So what I am doing right now is removing Fragment frag in its onActivityResult using childfragment transaction and pop it from back stack.
But its not working properly some time when I go back from activity Ba , Fragment frag is showing up. What I am doing wrong and what is the right way?

Comment: how many times have you added said fragment to the ui? how exactly are you poping it? are you sure it's not embedded in the ui? are you not creating a new instance that is being run in some oncreate/onresume scenario?

Comment: i am adding Fragment frag whenever i click a button in fragment Fa. when in fragment Frag , I click back pressed  i am checking backstack entry count and pooing it. when I start activity Ba, I am popping fragment frag in onactivity result of fragment frag using remove and popback stack. @LenaBru

Comment: @PJL have a look at it.

Comment: can you post some code please ?